# Check to see if the record exists - APEX

Tags: apex, soql

EDIT:

Map.ContainsKey is not working correctly and here are the details:

in my `assetRoles` i have the following one record:
`DEBUG|assetRoles {a0Gj000000Oni9NEBR=Asset_Role__c:{Id=a0Gj000000Oni9NEBR, Name=Administrator, Asset_id__c=a02j0000016wjyEAAQ}}`

the `RightOptionMap: I have : 
{a02j0000016wjyEAAQ, a02j0000009ehrpAAA, a02j0000018f3dhAAA}`

so based on the above data, the valid Ids are **a02j0000009ehrpAAA**, **a02j0000018f3dhAAA**

- **a02j0000016wjyEAAQ** in assetRoles >> Asset_id__c
- **a02j0000016wjyEAAQ** in RightOptionMap

when I do the system.debug I'm getting all thr three Ids? it should get me only two (**a02j0000009ehrpAAA**, **a02j0000018f3dhAAA**)

EDIT END

I have a situation where I'm checking to see if the record exists.

the `assetRoles` query returns two records:
the `RightOptionMap` has five records

```
Asset_Role__c[] assetRoles = new Asset_Roles__c[0];
assetRoles = [SELECT id,name... FROM Asset_Role__c where id =: 'xxxx'];


for(Asset_Role__c ar : assetRoles)
{
   for(Id aId : RightOptionMap.keySet())
   {
     if(ar.Id != aid)
     {
       system.debug('INSERT new record ');
     }
     else
     {
       system.debug('already exists');
     }
}
```

The problem I'm having with the above logic is that its inserting twice, it should check to see if the Id exists in the `assetRoles` if it is then do not insert otherwise insert.

```
assetRoles Ids =  `a02j12300008KSxhAAG, a02j1230007pUwBAAU`

RightOptionMap Ids = `{a02j1230007pUwBAAU, a02j1230008KSxhAAG, a02j0000008f3drAAA, a02j0000008f3dwAAA, a02j0000008f3e6AAA}`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a map of `Asset_Role__c`, it's easier to see if it contains any ids without needing to do a for loop within another for loop

```
List<Asset_Role__c> validAssets = new List<Asset_Role__c>();
Map<Id,Asset__Role__c> assetRoles = new Map<Id,Asset__Role__c>();
for(Asset__Role__c asset : [Soql query])
{
   assetRole.put(asset.Asset_id__c, asset)
}

for(Id aId : RightOptionMap.keySet())
{
   if(!assetRoles.containsKey(aid))
   {
       validAssets.add(rightOptionMap.get(aid));
   }
}
insert validAssets;
```

Also make sure that you will bulkify the code, and not write any DML operations in the for loop

Comment: I have updated my question, please have a look,  the Map.containsKey is not working correctly, explained detail in my question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you store in rightoptionmap and how it relates to your custom object Asset__Role__c. The method should work fine, the problem might be with how you link the various records.

Comment: rightoptionmap stores only ids `{a02j0000016wjyEAAQ, a02j0000009ehrpAAA, a02j0000018f3dhAAA}`

Comment: I think I understood you better, I've updated my answer